FTP Server can be accessed locally but not from other networks
I have set up an FTP server from microsoft IIS to communicate with some 4G cameras that I have placed in the field (that support FTP). Right now I am testing this server to troubleshoot why it doesn't work.
My LAN ip is the typical 192.168.1.7 which I have also port forwarded on my router and my public ip address is 79... I can log in to this FTP server (from winSCP and filezila) from any device as long as it's on my home network, but as soon as I try to connect from a 4g connection it always times out.
There is no clear solution online as every post points me in a different direction and seeing as I don't know much about networking this has stumped me.
From what I gather this is likely an issue with some firewall (although somewhere I read that the specific router that I have doesn't have to deactivate it's firewall to allow FTP connections). I have also been on the phone with tech support from the internet provider company, they helped me set up the port forwarding and told me that everything is fine on their end, so the server not connecting with other networks is something on my end and not in the router's configuration (??).
Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated.
I haven't tried much as information in scarce. I did follow a tutorial when creating the FTP server and I set it up correctly (afaik) with changes to firewall rules and everything.

Which connection is the one that times out – the control connection on port 21, or a data connection?

If you can connect from inside but not outside, then your router is not setup to forward packets properly. Give us the make/model of your router then we can look up the manual for it and maybe be of more help

To do basic troubleshooting, on a windows computer that you can place externally (eg, mobile hotspot), do a paping to the public wan ip address and the ftp port and keep it running. If it times out, the connection is blocked. Test various things, like temporarily disable firewall until the paping works. Now you know where it is blocked, and you can fix it accordingly. If the firewall is disabled and it still doesn't work, then doublecheck the nat rules again. Test with other ports, get a situation that you know works, and modify it so that the ftp works
